# Sorting datetime objects in Python with timezone imported from SQL

Tags: python-3.x, list, sorting, datetime

I have a list of datetime objects in a Python list and want to sort it using .sort().
Reading other similar questions, this is fairly straight forward and should do the job.

But it seems to be not working in my case.
I have following datetime objects

```
d1 = datetime.datetime(2017, 2, 20, 14, 25, 10, tzinfo=<git.objects.util.tzoffset object at 0x7f773d9c02d0>)
d2 = datetime.datetime(2017, 2, 20, 15, 11, 44, tzinfo=<git.objects.util.tzoffset object at 0x7f773d9c02d0>)
d1<d2 # returns false which is incorrect
d1.tzname() #returns 'fixed' for both d1 and d2
```

I am not sure if there are any other aspect of datetime object I am missing. The datetime list is populated extracting from SQL . Extracting from SQL is pretty straight forward and does not seem relevant to this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not entirely sure whats going on but the underlying reason for the comparison result is obtained by .astimezone()

```
d1 = datetime.datetime(2017, 2, 20, 16, 25, 10, tzinfo=datetime.timezone(datetime.timedelta(days=-1, seconds=64800), 'CST'))
d2 = datetime.datetime(2017, 2, 20, 16, 11, 44, tzinfo=datetime.timezone(datetime.timedelta(days=-1, seconds=64800), 'CST'))
```